# Bump Causing Bumps? (Not the right ones)

Tags: texturing, normal-map

So I made a bump map for this model I've been working on and it *works* but it leaves these lumps.[image]

My bump map doesn't have anything like that on it yet it still causes these no matter how I change the colour scaling.[image]
I'm guessing it could be those seed things the texture has but they look too big. Any help would be great.

Comment: maybe your unwrap is not good?

Comment: make sure your model is unwrapped. Go to your UV editor hit "N" to bring up the side panel, under display check "stretch" change to area. If you see any read or orange that is bad, it means you need to fix your uvs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those weird circular/truncated conical bumps are in fact in your bump map texture.  At least, I see them when I apply your texture to a simple unwrapped object using the "bump" node.  It's the white circles in your texture that are the culprit; they have a gradient around them which makes the cone shape.